# Spring Data test repository with propagation setting

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-boot-test

Here is a test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
public class ValidationTest {
  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager
  ...
}
```

I would like to test the service:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public boolean isEmailUnique(String emailAddress) {
  Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(emailAddress);
  ...
}
```

So to do it I create and save an entity:

```
entityManager.persist(new User(name: "abc", email: "abc@email.com"))
entityManager.flush()
```

and finally calling the request:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("..."))
```

What am I missing that the `userRepository.findByEmail()` does not see an inserted entity?
ps: if I remove the `@Transactional` from the method then the test works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment you act in is difficult to understand because you only provide some excerpts! But from what I see I would guess that...

If you annotate your test with `@Transactional`, every test method is surrounded with a new transaction that is automatically rolled back after the test method is executed.

If you now prepare some data in your test method it is visible in the scope of the implicit created transaction. If you then call your service method and this service method wants to have a new transaction, this new transaction does not 'see' the data you prepared in the outer transaction. If you remove the `@Transactional` annotation from the service method, the repository can now 'see' the data.

If you have a look into the javadoc of the `Propagation` enum, you will see that `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` is described the following way:

```
Create a new transaction, and suspend the current transaction if one exists.
```

The question is, why do they necessarily need a **new** transaction even if one already exists? Can't they just create a new one if none is available yet, but use the existing one if one already exists? That would be the case with the `SUPPORTS` propagation, that is configured by default on the `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: Thank you! I had to add a `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` or `NOT_SUPPORTED` on the service-method or even on the `userRepository.findByEmail` by itself to use this call during the validation. If I keep the single transaction then the spring will save the data into db and only then calls a validation with the another db-request inside it.

Comment: Well, agree. My bad. I guess I should split the test into two parts and prepare the data before the test by itself. It should be visible then.